# Firefox HTML inspector: how to copy single HTML tag?

Tags: html, firefox

I have a website and need to transport a form to another website. I however only need certain tags not the whole form block with all it's tables and divs.

When selecting a html-tag in inspector, I can copy inner HTML, outer HTML or CSS styles but how can I just copy that very exact tag I selected without it's child nodes, just the selected line in HTML code?

I ask this because the HTML is **minified** and I can't just select and copy a tag in source. Same when I chose "copy outer HTML" I get the whole HTML subtree minified, means everything in one line.

How can I quickly search and copy certain tags from the three without grabbing everything in the branch?

Edit: People, thanks for all your suggestions but please note that I wrote about a **MINIFIED** HTML page I have here.

Comment: you can press f2 on html-tag in inspector  and it will show content in box. then select and copy it from box. Hope this help.

Comment: @RV that's the same as selecting edit HTML from dropdown menu on the tag. I can not do that because the page is MINIFIED

Answer (score 2):

Just open `Debugger` near `Inspector`

Then find page file... then copy with any select range as you want

[image]

**UPDATE**
if it minify click here
[image]

Comment: I could do that, or I could use page source. But both doesn't work because the whole site is minified, that means everything is in one line. I'll be scrolling for ages finding the tags I want to copy.

Comment: But that's js not html. For html this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want try this

[image]

Comment: No. Please read my question,  can't use that because it gives me the whole subtree which is minified, thus everything in a line. I want to copy ONLY the selected tag

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seems unsolved yet, let me come up with a creative approach I use for similar tasks from time to time:

**(1) Creative solution: Page manipulation**

If you don't have a javascript framework of your choice (e.g. jQuery) on that page, add it using a browser-extension that adds it when page has loaded.

Then you write a bit of javascript code that removes unwanted child elements of the desired parents in a loop or so. That sounds like lots of work but since you asked this question I assume you need dozens if not hundreds of elements so it might be worth taking the time to write such loop(s).

When the code you injected processed the page and removed everything you don't want, you can then copy the code like mentioned by others here.

---

**(2) Alternative solution: Beautify the code beforhand**

If the given solution(s) don't work for you, one could try to beautify the code by copying the source to a webpage that auto-indends html/js code. You could then optionally save it into a html-file and approach that one again like mentioned here before.

---

**Sidenote**

If either this idea is too much work or you need this frequently you are probably approaching this on the wrong side. When working on frontend (only) you are always limited to what you have. If you could approach from the backend you could then build from the data/information whatever you need. If you could provide a bit more information about why you need this and how much code you are talking about one could maybe come up with a more sustainable solution!